# ASP.NET Core after login redirecting back to login page

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have just published asp.net core app to Azure Web Apps I use Asp.net core Identity and Entity Framework to authentication and authorization this app on my pc working very well but that error occurred after published, I have tried to clear cash and delete cookies in my browser unfortunately didn't work for me the problem is that after successfully login redirect to the login page I have no Idea what is the problem? this is startup.cs code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FeulApp.AppInfrastructure;
using FeulApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Globalization;

namespace FeulApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();


         
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConstr")));

            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

             
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(
                options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";


                });

             


            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => { options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied"); });

            
            
            //start here to add localization

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();


            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var cultures = new List<CultureInfo> {

    
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
        new CultureInfo("en")

                };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en");
                options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
            });

            //End here to add localization

        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
               app.UseHsts();
            }

           

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

        
            app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);



            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
         



            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
               
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Identity scheme migrated correctly in database?

Comment: So what is your error message?

Comment: @tmsbrndz  Yes the migrations is correct.

Comment: @Rena I don't get any error

Comment: Thank you guys, I fixed that issue it related to connection string and I published it aging every thing worked  well.